# Borders created with background colors disappear when bootstrap included

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a HTML table in which a background color is set on each cell. As a result, the contrast between two bg colors appears as a border. Please refer to accepted solution at

[Borders around every cell and table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229976/borders-around-every-cell-and-table?noredirect=1#45230065)

This is a follow up question.

Now I need to include bootstrap in my application. However, as soon as I include bootstrap CSS the border appearance disappears (even if I don't include any bootstrap class). How can I include bootstrap and still have a border like appearance around each cell.

Here is the fiddle with bootstrap included

https://jsfiddle.net/hqkw4x1s/1/

and below is the original code, without reference to bootstrap css (this gives a border like appearance due to bgcolors)

```css
.lab {
 HEIGHT: 18px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6f6f6
}

.val {
 PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-TOP: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white
}
```

```html
  <FORM>
           <DIV>
              <TABLE width="100%" bgColor=#cecece border=0 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=0>
                 <TBODY>
                    <TR vAlign=middle>
                       <TD width="6%" class=lab>Country</TD>
                       <TD width="44%" class=val>
                          <INPUT name="A" id="A" type=checkbox CHECKED>
                          <LABEL for="A">A</LABEL>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <INPUT name="B" id="B" type=checkbox CHECKED>
                          <LABEL for="B">B</LABEL>

                       </TD>
                       <TD width="6%" class=lab>States</TD>
                       <TD width="44%" class=val>
                          <TABLE width="100%" border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
                             <TBODY>
                                <TR>
                                   <TD>
                                      <SELECT>
                                         <OPTION value="p" selected>P</OPTION>
                                         <OPTION value="q">Q</OPTION>
                                         <OPTION value="r">R</OPTION>                                 
                                      </SELECT>
                                   </TD>                              
                                </TR>
                             </TBODY>
                          </TABLE>
                       </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR vAlign=middle>
                       <TD class=lab>Ownership</TD>
                       <TD class=val>
                          <TABLE width="100%" border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
                             <TBODY>
                                <TR>
                                   <TD><TEXTAREA style="WIDTH: 95%" rows=1 cols=20></TEXTAREA></TD>
                                   <TD style="WIDTH: 75px; TEXT-ALIGN: left"><SPAN 
                                      style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f8f8f8"></SPAN> 
                                   </TD>
                                </TR>
                             </TBODY>
                          </TABLE>
                       </TD>
                       <TD class=lab>Partnership</TD>
                       <TD class=val><INPUT  type=text xHeight="32px"> </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR vAlign=middle>
                       <TD class=lab>Accounts Payable</TD>
                       <TD 
                          style="PADDING-LEFT: 2px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white">
                          <INPUT type=text>
                       </TD>
                       <TD class=lab>Start Date</TD>
                       <TD class=val>

                          <INPUT type=text xHeight="32px"> 
                       </TD>
                    </TR>

                 </TBODY>
              </TABLE>
           </DIV>
        </FORM>
```

Comment: Below answer is working well for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update below table tag.**Here you just need to use the bootstrap standard class to achieve this.**

**Instead**

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#cecece" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
```

**Should be:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" bgcolor="#cecece" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
```